# Saving changing variable value in flutter

Tags: flutter, variables, save, sharedpreferences

I want to save a variable's value that changes every 5 seconds then read it. I have already tried saving it to shared preferences then reading it but the problem with that was that the value was only saved one time and did not save the changes done to the variable. Is there a way to implement that in flutter?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
void initState() {

    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _connect();
    });

  }


...


      void predict(List<double> v) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    List<List<double>> L=List<List<double>>.filled(1, [0], growable: true);
    L[0]=v;
    ...
    String res=response.body;
    Map R = json.decode(res);
    var _list = R.values.toList();
    print(res);
    Proba= double.parse(_list[1]);
    

    await prefs.setDouble('Proba', Proba);
    
    
    }
    ....
class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  Page({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  PageState createState() => PageState();
}

class PageState extends State<Page> {
.....
  Future<double> _getProbaFromSharedPref() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getDouble("Proba") ?? 0;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Location1=_getCurrentLocation();
    _getStringFromSharedPref();
    _getProbaFromSharedPref().then((s) {
      Value = s;
      
    });

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _check();
    });

  }
}
```

In the code I tried saving the variable in sharedPreferences then reading it, but I have no clue on how to reload it everytime it changes.

Comment: How did you save the variable? saving it should automatically update it's value if it has changed, can you show the code in which you update the shared preferences?

Comment: I posted a sample code to give an idea about what I have tried.

Comment: The code seems to be correct to me, is it throwing any error by chance? Is `Proba` a field within your state class?

Comment: Proba is in my app State

Comment: So, just to understand the problem, you're changing the variable within the SharedPreferences and displaying it on the screen but the variable on the screen doesn't update?

Comment: Yes that's the problem.

Comment: Oh ok, try to call `setState((){})` after you await for the changes to sharedPreferences. await `prefs.setDouble('Proba', Proba);`